# Getting Error : System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, mysql, web-services, .net-3.5

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I get this error while I try to test my webservice method on my local host. I get the error on this line.

```
public ICampgroundsNearMeManager campgroundsNearMeManager = ManagerFactory.CreateCampgroundsNearMeManager();
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have installed the correct version of Microsoft Enterprise Library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

Seemed to be a problem with the DLL file which I had imported. Removed the DLL, cleaned and build the project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting more information using the [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).